# Zoom to specific cordinates in catia using macro

Tags: vba, catia, caa

I am trying to write a macro that requires to Zoom into a specific dimension in the drawing....and I researched about it but couldn't find a way to do that.

I am unsure of it....but I saw somewhere(couldn't find that link now) that if you have coordinates to where you want to zoom, then it can be done....does anyone know anything about it?

please let me know....and thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have a look on the _Viewpoint2D_ object and the method _PutOrigin_

Comment: Hi, @Shrotter ........i tried doing the above but i am getting an error saying "function or interface marked as restricted", i am writing the macro in catvba format

Comment: So have a look on https://v5vb.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/restricted-interfaces/

Comment: Thankyou @Shrotter, got the issue rectified, I was binding the objects before the Viewpoint2d Objects like viewer, window etc.....which shouldn't be done.